# useEffect infinite looping issue Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am trying to create a preloader so that when the content is still loading my loader spins and when the loading is done the loader will be gone as well.
What happens is the site gets stuck on the loading page and it loads infinitely.
I tried a lot of ways to fix this but could not.
How can I fix this? I am new to this, and still learning.

````
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export default function Loader() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isFadeClass, setFadeClass] = useState(false);

//     This was working
//     window.addEventListener("load", function () {
//         setTimeout(() => {
//             setFadeClass(true);
//         }, 1000);

//         setTimeout(() => {
//             setIsLoading(false);
//         }, 1500);
//     }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const handleLoad = () => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setFadeClass(true);
                }, 1000);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }, 1500);
            };

            window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
            };
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`LOADER_WRAPPER${isLoading ? "_SHOW" : ""}${isFadeClass ? " fade-effect" : ""}`}>
                <span className='loader'></span>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

the second argument in useEffect is an array of variables to listen to, an empty array means only listen to the mounting and unmounting of the component.

In your specific example just remove all the window load listener bits, react handles that for you so you don't need to worry about listening DOM load events.

```
useEffect(() => {
 // do stuff now the component is mounted

 return () => {
   // the component is about to be unmounted clean up here
 }
}, [])
```